# TerminalColours not loading in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, simbl, terminal-color

I've installed SIMBL and downloaded TerminalColors, then copied this bundle to Plugins directory to SIMBL/Plugins. Everytime I started the Terminal, the following message was shown:

> Terminal 2.3 (v309) has not been tested with the plugin
> TerminalColours (null) (v1.0). As a precaution, it has not been
> loaded. Please contact the plugin developer for further information.

After some search I found that other users had the same problem and solved by modifying the Info.plist and setting the `MaxBundleVersion` string value to the same version of the terminal. In my case it would be 309 or v309. I've tested both.

When I start the Terminal, the message appears no more. But the "More" button in the Text tab of Settings never appears.

Does someone know the solution or have a suggestion?

Note: I've already rebooted the system.

Comment: Why are you using the SIMBL TerminalColors? Terminal.app natively supports changing the color, and iTerm2 is way better then apple's terminal...

Comment: @demure Thanks for your suggestion about iTerm. I will use it. But again about Terminal.app: I've read that TerminalColors gives more options to configure the appearence than the native settings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was 'back in the day', before terminal gained the options natively. At least that is how I remember SIMBL, back when it was relevant.

Comment: @demure So it seems nowadays "TerminalColours" is futile. I can do changes in the bash profile too... I'm really losing my patience about it so I will reconsider if this waste of time is worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal has had options to customize ANSI colors since 10.7, so [TerminalColours](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/01/customising-colours-in-leopard-terminal) is no longer needed.

Screenshots of Terminal in 10.8 and TerminalColours:

[image]
[image]

If you have 10.6 or 10.5, you could also try using [TerminalColoreopard](http://niw.at/articles/2007/11/02/TerminalColoreopard/en).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will definitively ignore TerminalColours.